Separadores decimais no português brasileiro e português europeu
É correcto dizer que em Portugal usa-se vírgula como separador decimal e espaço para separar grupos 3 dígitos, e no Brasil usa-se além disto o ponto como separador de 3 dígitos?




Portugal
Brasil




Separador Decimal
Vírgula (,)
Vírgula (,)


Separador de Grupos de 3 Dígitos
Espaço ( )
Espaço ( ) ou Ponto (.)



Por exemplo.

50 212,050 kg - correcto em Portugal e no Brasil
150.212,050 kg - incorrecto em Portugal, mas correcto no Brasil


Resumo: Em ambos os países é preferível usar em textos a vírgula como separador decimal e omitir o delimitador ou usar o espaço para esta função.

A tabela está essencialmente correta (lembrando apenas que o uso do delimitador de milhares, milhões, etc. é facultativo), especialmente com relação à vírgula como separador decimal1. Contudo, o uso do ponto como delimitador (separador de grupos de dígitos) a rigor deve ser evitado também no Brasil, por mais tradicional e arraigado que seja (como atesta o Manual de redação da Folha de São Paulo).
Já há décadas que as organizações internacionais responsáveis determinaram o uso do espaço como delimitador (Wikipédia):

Desde 2003, o uso de espaços como separadores (por exemplo: 20 000 e 1 000 000, para "vinte mil" e "um milhão", respectivamente) foi oficialmente aprovado pelo SI / padrão 31-0 ISO, bem como pelo Escritório Internacional de Pesos e Medidas e pela União Internacional de Química Pura e Aplicada (IUPAC)

Normas internacionais estas, que foram acolhidas não apenas em Portugal, como também pela brasileira ABNT (exemplo) e pelo Livro de Estilo da Wikipédia em português (que descreve normas amplamente aceitas na Wikipédia lusófona).
A melhor defesa que encontrei da adoção de convenções internacionais em detrimento de tradições locais foi feita pela Helena Figueira no FLIP, que é válido reproduzir na íntegra:

separadores numéricos [Ortografia]
Como se escreve, em números, um milhão? Com pontos, sem pontos e com espaços ou sem pontos e sem espaços? 1.000.000, 1 000 000 ou 1000000?
C. S. (Espanha)
Não há qualquer norma ortográfica para o uso de um separador das classes de algarismos (unidades, milhares, milhões, etc.) ou para o separador das casas decimais, pois o Acordo Ortográfico de 1945 e o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 (os textos legais reguladores da ortografia portuguesa) são omissos.
Há várias opiniões sobre o assunto e a maioria dos livros de estilo (veja-se, a título de exemplo, o texto disponibilizado pelo jornal Público no seu Livro de Estilo, artigo "Números", ponto 1.), prontuários e consultores linguísticos para o português defende o uso do ponto a separar as classes de algarismos (ex.: 1.000.000) e da vírgula para separar a parte inteira da parte decimal (ex.: 100,5).
Como se trata de uma questão de metrologia, mais do que de ortografia, a resolução n.º 10 (https://www.bipm.org/fr/CGPM/db/22/10/) da 22.ª Conferência Geral de Pesos e Medidas (Paris, 12 - 17 de Outubro de 2003) organizada pelo Bureau International des Poids et Mesures, em que Portugal participou, é importante e pode contribuir para a uniformização nesta questão (esta resolução apenas reforça a resolução n.º 7 [https://www.bipm.org/fr/CGPM/db/9/7/] da 9.ª Conferência ocorrida em 1948, que apontava no mesmo sentido): o símbolo do separador decimal poderá ser a vírgula ou o ponto (sobretudo nos países anglo-saxónicos e em teclados de computadores e calculadoras); apenas para facilitar a leitura, os números podem ser divididos em grupos de três algarismos (que correspondem às classes das unidades, milhares, milhões, etc.), a contar da direita, mas estes grupos não devem nunca ser separados por pontos ou por vírgulas (ex.: 1 000 000,5 ou 1 000 000.5 e não 1.000.000,5 ou 1,000,000.5).
Por respeito pelas convenções internacionais e por uma questão de rigor (é fácil de concluir que a utilização do ponto ou da vírgula para separar as classes de algarismos num número que contenha casas decimais pode gerar equívocos), é aconselhável não utilizar outro separador para as classes de algarismos senão o espaço (ex.: 1000000 ou 1 000 000).
Bibliografia: Guilherme de ALMEIDA, Sistema Internacional de Unidades (SI) - Grandezas e Unidades Físicas - Terminologia, símbolos e recomendações, Plátano Ed., 3.ª ed., Lisboa: 2002, pp 48-50.
Ver também: escrita de numerais, bilião e outros grandes números
Sites a consultar: Instituto Português da Qualidade; Bureau International des Poids et Mesures

Digno de menção, ainda que não estandardizado, é o uso do apóstrofo como delimitador, que pode se mostrar particularmente útil em textos manuscritos, em que a delimitação por espaços pode não ficar suficientemente clara. De modo geral, no entanto, seu uso não é recomendado.
1 Numa nota pessoal, e em linha como argumento da internacionalização exposto acima, lamento que não consigamos estabelecer um símbolo internacionalmente aceito como separador decimal (como já feito com unidades de medida, nomenclatura em biologia, etc.). Especialmente em sistemas de informação, essa 'diversidade' não gera nada além de prejuízo.

A linguagem de programação C, na sua revisão de ~2023 (C23), suporta ' como separador de dígitos. A linguagem C++ na sua revisão de 2014 também o faz. Outras mais antigas, como FORTRAN e Ada, também.

@Schilive Sim, há uma infinidade de notações e formatações aceitas nas mais diferentes linguagens, Python por exemplo aceita o 'underscore' (_) como delimitador.
